# How can I set the text for a label equal to the selected Item of a databound listBox?

Tags: vb.net

I've set the DisplayMember for the ListBox to the "Employee" column, and the ValueMember to the "EmpID" column. The listbox populates fine, but the label never changes. I'm new at this and can't figure out what I'm missing. Here's my code:

```
Me.EmployeeTableAdapter.Fill(Me.TimeCards2DataSet.Employee)

Label1.Text = lstEmployees.SelectedItem.ToString
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the SelectedIndexChanged event:

```
Private Sub lstEmployees_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
                         Handles lstEmployees.SelectedIndexChanged
  If lstEmployees.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
    Label1.Text = String.Empty
  Else
    Label1.Text = lstEmployees.SelectedValue.ToString
  End If
End Sub
```

Alternatively, if using DataBinding:

```
Label1.DataBindings.Add("Text", Me.TimeCards2DataSet.Employee, "Employee")
```

Comment: It's a lot closer now. After making the modifications to my code, the label text now reads System.Data.DataRowView.

Comment: @Jako'theShadows Updated answer.  Try using `SelectedValue` instead, otherwise, you would have to use a DirectCast.